# GWT RPC cannot compile the project

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, twitter4j

This question is an extension of previous question. [GWT Cannot compile the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117072/gwt-cannot-compile-the-project/9117396)

Please have a look and tell me what's wrong with it.

**Client side.**

Twitter.java

```
package in.isuru.twitter.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import twitter4j.Tweet;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable.FlexCellFormatter;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
*/
public class Twitter implements EntryPoint {


private final TwitterServiceAsync searchService = GWT.create(TwitterService.class);

public void onModuleLoad() {

     // Create a Flex Table
    final FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
    FlexCellFormatter cellFormatter = flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter();
    flexTable.addStyleName("cw-FlexTable");
    flexTable.setWidth("32em");
    flexTable.setCellSpacing(5);
    flexTable.setCellPadding(3);

    // Add some text
    cellFormatter.setHorizontalAlignment(0, 1, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cellFormatter.setColSpan(0, 0, 2);

    searchService.search("love", new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Tweet>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            //Not yet completed.

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Tweet> result) {
            for (int i=0 ; i <result.size() ; i++) {
                Tweet tweet = result.get(i);
                String user = tweet.getFromUser();
                String status = tweet.getText();
                addRow(flexTable, user);
                addRow(flexTable, status);

        }


    }});


    flexTable.ensureDebugId("cwFlexTable");
    RootPanel.get().add(flexTable);
  }

  /**
   * Add a row to the flex table.
   */
  private void addRow(FlexTable flexTable, String status) {
    int numRows = flexTable.getRowCount();
    flexTable.setText(numRows, 0, status);
    flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 1, numRows + 1);
  }

  /**
   * Remove a row from the flex table.
   */
  private void removeRow(FlexTable flexTable) {
    int numRows = flexTable.getRowCount();
    if (numRows > 1) {
      flexTable.removeRow(numRows - 1);
      flexTable.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 1, numRows - 1);
    }

}
}
```

TwitterService.java

```
package in.isuru.twitter.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import twitter4j.Tweet;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("search")
 public interface TwitterService extends RemoteService {
ArrayList<Tweet> search(String searchTerm) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

TwitterServiceAsync.java

```
package in.isuru.twitter.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import twitter4j.Tweet;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface TwitterServiceAsync {

void search(String searchTerm, AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Tweet>> callback) throws llegalArgumentException;
}
```

**Server Side**

```
package in.isuru.twitter.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Tweet;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import in.isuru.twitter.client.TwitterService;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class TwitterServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements TwitterService {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

@Override
public ArrayList<Tweet> search(String searchTerm) {
    // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    Query query = new Query(searchTerm);
    QueryResult result = null;
    try {
        result = twitter.search(query);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Tweet tweet : result.getTweets()) {
        //System.out.println(tweet.getFromUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
        tweets.add(tweet);

    }

    return tweets;
}

 }
```

Twitter.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='twitter'>
 <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

 <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
 <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
 <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
 <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
 <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
 <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->


 <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

 <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
 <entry-point class='in.isuru.twitter.client.Twitter'/>

 <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
 <source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

Error is

> [DEBUG] [twitter] - Validating newly compiled units [TRACE] [twitter]
>   - Finding entry point classes     [ERROR] [twitter] - Errors in 'file:/E:/workspace/Twitter/src/in/isuru/twitter/client/Twitter.java'
>         [ERROR] [twitter] - Line 43: No source code is available for type
>   twitter4j.Tweet; did you forget to inherit a required module?     [ERROR]
>   [twitter] - Errors in
>   'file:/E:/workspace/Twitter/src/in/isuru/twitter/client/TwitterServiceAsync.java'
>         [ERROR] [twitter] - Line 11: No source code is available for type
>   twitter4j.Tweet; did you forget to inherit a required module?     [ERROR]
>   [twitter] - Unable to find type 'in.isuru.twitter.client.Twitter'
>         [ERROR] [twitter] - Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made
>   this type unavailable         [ERROR] [twitter] - Hint: Check the
>   inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a
>   required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries
>   properly [ERROR] [twitter] - Failed to load module 'twitter' from user
>   agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7' at 127.0.0.1:7901

Answer (score 0):

class `twitter4j.Tweet` cannot be used in client code since it is not included in any inherited GWT module. You need to create your own transfer object class, for example `TweetDTO` somewhere in your `client` or `shared` packages. Only this object should be used in interfaces `TwitterServiceAsync`  and `TwitterService`. Then in your servlet, you create `TweetDTO` copy required values from `Tweet` to `TweetDTO` and then return a list of `TweetDTO`.